# How to fix [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

im try to make restart program using button tkinter python. but when i run it and press the button, it said [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Here my error = C:\Program: can't open file 'C:\Users\ROG FLOW\Desktop\Untuk SIDANG TA\Untuk Upload Ke google drive\Files\Python310\python.exe': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Can anyone help me with that ? i appreciate every help

```
import sys`
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

def restart_me():
   pth = sys.executable
   os.execl(pth, pth, *sys.argv)

root = Tk()
Label(root, text="hi there!").pack()

Label(root, text="hi there!").pack()
Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_me).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better to post the full error traceback.

Comment: Welcome! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: `C:\Program:` makes it smell like your path is being split into individual words rather than parsed as a single string. Can you reproduce this problem on any operating system other than Windows?

Comment: i cannot, because i dont have other operating system other than windows

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `os.execl()` cannot handle file path with spaces inside properly.  It works fine when there is no space inside the file path.

I would suggest to use `subprocess.Popen()` instead and you need to destroy current main window before calling it:

```py
...
import subprocess
import sys
...

def restart_me():
    root.destroy()
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, *sys.argv])

...
```

Note that `subprocess.Popen()` will not replace current process so that is why the current main window need to be destroyed.